# RAID1 "conflicting device node" message on startup

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, raid

I'm dual booting Win8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 (Gnome Classic). I have RAID1 set up (on Asus Z87-A motherboard) with Win partition, Ubuntu partition, and NTFS partition for data.

On Ubuntu startup, I see messages:

> conflicting device node '/dev/mapper/isw_bdjiccgcbg_ARRAY1p6' found,
>   link to '/dev/dm-6' will not be created conflicting device node
>   '/dev/mapper/isw_bdjiccgcbg_ARRAY1p6' found, link to '/dev/dm-6' will
>   not be created

When I start GParted, I get following error messages:

> Could not stat device /dev/mapper//dev/sbd: "pdc" and "isw" formats
>   discovered (using isw)! - No such file or directory Could not stat
>   device /dev/mapper//dev/sda: "pdc" and "isw" formats discovered (using
>   isw)! - No such file or directory

However, I have no problems mounting and using NTFS partition.
Are those messages something I should worry about?

Comment: I have almost the same message for my three EXT4 Partitions: `systemd-udevd[675]: conflicting device node '/dev/mapper/isw_cghbfjjcca_matrix2' found, link to '/dev/dm-2' will not be created`, what is this ?

Comment: I have a very similar problem except I'm using Linux Mint & Windows 7 & 'fake' raid 0.

Comment: My computer has the same problem during the system boot.

Comment: This sounds like the fake RAID device driver sees the same disks through two different protocols, but it enables only one. IOW it should be fairly harmless, but it's hard to tell without more information. In any case, please post more information, e.g. `dmsetup ls`, `dmraid -r`, `lsblk` etc.

Comment: Do you still have this issue? Did you come to a resolution?

Comment: @ElderGeek The OP last signed on Oct 27, 2014. I'm afraid a response is unlikely.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Agreed. VTC as non-repro

Comment: @ElderGeek silly me I should have voted that in first place. Voting along with you. Something today between me an two AU moderators might be of interest to you with this question: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17094/can-we-merge-these-three-qas?noredirect=1#comment35128_17094 I'd appreciate your thoughts there with the "non-repro" angle. If you don't mind :)

Comment: I am not dual booting Windows with Ubuntu anymore, so I can't reproduce this either. I have never experienced any issues with my setup, so those messages were most likely completely harmless. I never figured out why I was getting them.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix as to the non-repro angle I don't have anything to add to what Zanna said there, and I concur with that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell me what raid configuration you have setup?
In your raid configuration are there indications of which is primary and is one of the drives set as a hot spare drive? 
I believe a hot spare needs to be set.

> Configuring the RAID
>
> ```
> Once you have completed your partitioning in the main "Partition Disks" page select "Configure Software RAID"
> Select "Yes"
> Select "Create new MD drive"
> Select RAID type: RAID 0, RAID 1, RAID 5 or RAID 6
> Number of devices. RAID 0 and 1 need 2 drives. 3 for RAID 5 and 4 for RAID 6.
> Number of spare devices. Enter 0 if you have no spare drive.
> select which partitions to use..
> Repeat steps 3 to 7 with each pair of partitions you have created.
> Filesystem and mount points will need to be specified for each RAID device. By default they are set to "do not use".
> Once done, select finish.
> ```

See here for complete info [info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID#Configuring_the_RAID)